# Merging property values of objects with common key with jq

Tags: json, jq

I have an array of objects with 2 properties, say "key" and "value":

```
[
   {key: 1, value: a}, 
   {key: 2, value: b}, 
   {key: 1, value: c}
]
```

Now, I would like to merge the values of the "value" properties of objects with the same "key" property value. That is the previous array is transformed into:

```
[
   {key: 1, value: [a, c]}, 
   {key: 2, value: [b]}
]
```

I tried something like:

```
$ echo '[{"key": "1", "val": "a"}, {"key": "2", "val": "b"}, {"key": "1", "val": "c"}]' | jq '. | group_by(.["key"]) | .[] | reduce .[] as $in ({"val": []}; {"key": $in.key, "val":  [$in.val] + .["val"]})'
```

But it triggers a jq syntax error and I have no idea why. I am stuck.

Any idea ?

Thanks

B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach using `reduce` could be sanitized to

```sh
jq 'group_by(.["key"]) | .[] |= reduce .[] as $in (
  {value: []}; .key = $in.key | .value += [$in.value]
)'
```

```json
[
  {
    "value": [
      "a",
      "c"
    ],
    "key": 1
  },
  {
    "value": [
      "b"
    ],
    "key": 2
  }
]
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/WzNfJOE3ZS)

Another approach using `map` would be

```sh
jq 'group_by(.key) | map({key: .[0].key, value: map(.value)})'
```

```json
[
  {
    "key": 1,
    "value": [
      "a",
      "c"
    ]
  },
  {
    "key": 2,
    "value": [
      "b"
    ]
  }
]
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/iWjjYQmX9s)